# Concatenate several XMLs to single

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008-r2, concatenation

I have the following XMLs generated in my SQL Server 2008 R2 database

```
<XMLData>
...
<Type>1</Type>
...
</XMLData>
```

The final output I need is single combined as follows:

```
<AllMyData>
    <XMLData>
        ...
        <Type>1</Type>
        ...
    </XMLData>
    <XMLData>
        ...
        <Type>2</Type>
        ...
    </XMLData>
    ...
    ...
    <XMLData>
        ...
        <Type>n</Type>
        ...
    </XMLData>
<AllMyData>
```

`n` is unknown until query is running.

Now I'm using this approach:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_GetErrorXML]
(   
    @DateFrom datetime,     
    @DateTo datetime,      
    @ResourceTypeID bigint,    
    @ServerID int           
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX) 
AS
BEGIN 

    DECLARE @ErrorDescription VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @ErrorDescription = '<root>';
    WITH CTE AS
    (   

        SELECT 
            d.GeneratedOnUtc,
            ErrorDescription = cast(d.Data as nvarchar(max))
        FROM dbo.AgentData d
          INNER JOIN dbo.Agent a ON a.CheckID = d.CheckID
          INNER JOIN dbo.Server s ON a.ServerID = s.ID
        WHERE d.EventType = 'Result' AND
              a.ResourceTypeID & @ResourceTypeID > 0 AND
              s.ID = @ServerID AND
              d.GeneratedOnUtc between @DateFrom AND @DateTo AND
              d.Result = 0                            
    )
    SELECT @ErrorDescription = @ErrorDescription + cte.ErrorDescription
    FROM CTE    
    ORDER BY cte.GeneratedOnUtc ASC

    RETURN(@ErrorDescription + '</root>')
END
```

where `d.Data` datatype is `xml not null`

but XML casts + UDF are so slooow and looks ugly.

Is there some better way to do it?

Comment: What type is d.Data and what type do you want as a result?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri `XML` or `string`, doesn't matter which one

Comment: Type of D.Data is XMl or string??? If doesn't metter then why are you casting to nvarchar?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri XML. Because I don't know how to concatenate XMLs. This is why I asked this question.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this?

```
with cte AS
(SELECT d.GeneratedOnUtc as gtime,
d.Data as xmlDat FROM dbo.AgentData d
INNER JOIN dbo.Agent a ON a.CheckID = d.CheckID
INNER JOIN dbo.Server s ON a.ServerID = s.ID
WHERE d.EventType = 'Result' AND
a.ResourceTypeID & @ResourceTypeID > 0 AND
s.ID = @ServerID AND
d.GeneratedOnUtc between @DateFrom AND @DateTo AND
d.Result = 0 
)
select CAST(cte.xmlDat AS XML) from cte order by cte.gtime for xml   path(''), root('root')
```

Comment: I tried the query posted by Giorgi Nakeuri, and compared the exec time of my query with CAST(col AS XML), his with xquery  and without xquery on a table with 1.025.484 rows. CAST(col AS XML) and his last query took 11 s and the xquery took 37 s. So I do not see a performance difference.

Comment: Because your statement is equal to my second statement. There will be same plan of course. But if additional tag is not acceptable then statement with xquery is the only way I think.

Comment: The additional tag gets eliminated with CAST(col AS XML). Otherwise why would I cast an XML column to XML? :)

Comment: Thanks. I never thought of this xquery technique to get rid of this unwanted tag. CAST was sort of a brute force approach.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer performance issue, which seems to be related to sql statement itself, or by using function in other statements. Try this. This returns result for 1.000.000 records within 15 sec, that is pretty good I think.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( x XML )

INSERT  INTO @t
        SELECT  '<XMLData><Type>1</Type></XMLData>'
        UNION
        SELECT  '<XMLData><Type>2</Type></XMLData>'

SELECT  x.query('/XMLData/*')
FROM    @t
FOR     XML PATH('XMLData') ,
            ROOT('AllMyData')
```

Output:

```
<AllMyData>
  <XMLData>
    <Type>1</Type>
  </XMLData>
  <XMLData>
    <Type>2</Type>
  </XMLData>
</AllMyData>
```

If additional tag is acceptable then you can do:

```
SELECT  x
FROM    @t
FOR     XML PATH(''), ROOT('AllMyData')
```

This query completes in 3 secs for 1.000.000 row and output is like:

```
<AllMyData>
  <x>
    <XMLData>
      <Type>1000000</Type>
    </XMLData>
  </x>
  <x>
    <XMLData>
      <Type>999999</Type>
    </XMLData>
  </x>
</AllMyData>
```